# Freenom domain on Google Site: doesn't work without prefix "www."

Tags: cname, google-sites

I created the domain example.tk on Freenom. I use that URL on a Google Site.
Everything works accordingly if you use "www.example.tk".
However if I only type "example.tk" nothing is displayed.
Can you please help me on this?

Thank you!

Comment: In DNS, do both www and the root domain use the same IP address?

Comment: I can point the subdomain to the desired website but not the root donain, freenom does not allow it. Solved using url forwarding on root domain. Thanks you!

Comment: Check your DNS zone settings to see if you have an "A" record for "www" entry of your domain then The "A" record should point to the same IP as your default main Domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the prefix 'www' it works because it's the subdomain the points to the desired google site. Using url forwarding from the naked domain to th subdomain does the trick.

Comment: I tried using the forwarding thing but it doesn't work. If I redirect to google.com it takes me there but when I redirect to my www subdomain, it doesn't... I am hosting on replit.com and my register is freenom... Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Freenom DNS for googles sites.

Add CNAME record:

- www  TTL- 3600 value- ghs.googlehosted.com

Add a Txt record:

- value = 'unique value verification text record from Google'

Naked domain as follows
Modify your A records so they have the A record values listed below. If necessary, create new A records to include a record for each IP

Name/Host/Alias Time to Live (TTL*) Record Type Value/Answer/Destination

- Blank or @   3600    A   216.239.32.21
- Blank or @   3600    A   216.239.34.21
- Blank or @   3600    A   216.239.36.21
- Blank or @   3600    A   216.239.38.21

Wait at least 1hr before submitting Google verification, you can check progress via  [www.whatsmydns.net](http://www.whatsmydns.net)
Once done head back to Google sites add your custom domain